# How to enable middle-button selection on trackpad?

Tags: x11, mouse

I'm able to select text with the left button and with the right button (if wm and application allows it (i.e emacs)). But the middle button is acting like a scroll wheel.

How can I change the behavior of the middle button from scroll wheel to a selection (like other two buttons)?